# split word into two partition in java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm making an file input and text output code.
I included input.txt and the content of the text is like underneath

```
4
100 Watched
2 Key holders
3 Stamps
30 Data structure textbooks
//entered between every number
```

and I like to make an output that the result is "Key holders"
but in my code, the output is "Key"

I don't know how to print the word "holders" next to the Key.
Of course I think the reason is because I spliced the word when every " " is seen. Then how can I slice the string with only two partition, consists of integer and the right side?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane.MaximizeAction;

public class Assignment11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        String entryString;
        entryString = in.readLine();

        int entryNum = Integer.valueOf(entryString);

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        String result = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < entryNum; i++){
            String temp; 
            temp = in.readLine();

            String entry[] = temp.split(" "); 
            int price = Integer.parseInt(entry[0]);

            if(price < min){
                min = price;
                result = entry[1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp.split(" ", 2)`?

Comment: it really works! thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

[String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) has an overload that takes a limit on how many parts to split the string into. In this case you simply want;

```
temp.split(" ", 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix your program is the following. Instead of using `term.split(" ")`, find the position of the first `space` in your string, and use that position to split your input line into two. The first part of the input line will be the number you want to parse, and the second part of the split will be the line that you want to print.

For example:

```
int a = term.indexOf(" ");
if (a != -1) {
   try{
       int price = Integer.parseInt(term.substring(0, a));
       if (price < min) {
           min = price;
           result = term.substring(a);
       }
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException e) {

   }
}
```